# Draw boxes in canvas using x y coordinate from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, image, rectangles

I am trying to draw in a panel of 1000 * 1000 a series of rectangles of three different colors. The x and y coordinates of each rectangle are taken from a mysql table (info_x and info_y).
If situations arise when reading other columns of the mysql table, the rectangle should be colored differently.
The table is 200 lines long, so I should expect 200 rectangles, scattered a bit around the panel, depending on the x and y coordinates read, and different colors depending on if situations arise.
If I just extract the data and print it on the screen everything works regularly. At the moment I try to draw the rectangles the script doesn't work anymore. Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?
thank you all...I'm sorry but I'm a beginner in the php field.
here my code

```
<?php
//Create a 1000 x 1000 image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(1000, 1000);
// Allocate colors
$pink = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 0, 255);
$white = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 255, 255, 255);
$green = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 132, 135, 28);
//--------------------------------------
$con=mysqli_connect("ip","name","pass","dabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$c=0;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_info1");
//<!--- PRIMA  tabella --- NUMERI L>
$results = $query or die (mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0){
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        $c++;
        $posto=$row['info_posto'];
        $dispo=$row['info_disponibile'];
        $ris=$row['info_cognome'];
        $xs=50;// offeset secondo angolo x
        $ys=50;// offeset secondo angolo y
        $x= $row['info_x'] ;// coordinata x da sql
        $y= $row['info_y'] ;//coordinata y da sql
            if($dispo==1 and $ris!=RISERVATO){
                imagerectangle($canvas, $x, $y, $x+$xs, $y+$ys $pink); // posto occupato
                //echo "occupato \n";
                }
            if($dispo==0 and $ris!=RISERVATO){
                imagerectangle($canvas, $x, $y, $x+$xs, $y+$ys, $white); // posto libero
                //echo "libero \n";
                }
            if($dispo==1 and $ris==RISERVATO){
                imagerectangle($canvas, $x, $y, $x+$xs, $y+$ys, $green); // posto riservato
                //echo "riservato \n";
                }
                //echo $c ;// solo un contatore , mi server per saper se il clico venifa effettuato
}
// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);
?>
```

[image: only one rectangle...insted of 200...sigh]

Comment: `$canvas, $x, $y, $x+$xs, $y+$ys $pink` --  You are missing a comma before `pink`

Comment: add some code if there are no rows returned and may a tutorial about debugging php code

Comment: thank's Zak...but it is not the problem...

Comment: Have you checked whether your conditions there are actually true? And where is the constant `RISERVATO` supposed to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

finally...solved.I rewrite all the procedure.
Thank anyway to all.
Mario[image]

```
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0){
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
        $posto=$row['info_posto'];
        $dispo=$row['info_disponibile'];
        $ris=$row['info_cognome'];
        $xs=20;
        $ys=20;
        $x= $row['info_x'];
        $y= $row['info_y'];
            if($dispo==1 and $ris!=RISERVATO){
                $colour = $red;}
                //echo $x ;}
            if($dispo==0 and $ris!=RISERVATO){
                $colour =$green;}
                //echo("libero");}
            if($dispo==1 and $ris==RISERVATO){
                $colour = $withe;}
                //echo("riserivato");}
                //imagerectangle($canvas, $x/15, $y/15, $x/15+$xs, $y/15+$ys, $colour);
                $text = $posto;
                //$text = XXX;
                $font = 'Verdana.ttf';
                imagefilledrectangle($canvas, $x/15, $y/15, $x/15+$xs, $y/15+$ys, $colour);
                //imagettftext($canvas,$x/15, $y/15, $x/15+$xs, $y/15+$ys, $colour, $font, $text);
                imagettftext($canvas,8, 0, $x/15+1, $y/15-10, $black, $font, $text);
    }
}

// Output and free from memor
imagejpeg($canvas);
imagedestroy($canvas);
```